# How to shuffle only a fraction of a column in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to shuffle a fraction (for example 40%) of the values of a specific column in a Pandas dataframe.

How would you do it? Is there a simple idiomatic way to do that, maybe using `np.random`, or `sklearn.utils.shuffle`?

I have searched and only found answers related to shuffling the whole column, or shuffling complete rows in the df, but none related to shuffling only a fraction of a column.

I have actually managed to do it, apparently, but I get a warning, so I figure even if in this simple example it seems to work, that is probably not the way to do it.

Here's what I've done:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'i':range(20),
                   'L':[chr(97+i) for i in range(20)]
                  })

df['L2'] = df['L']
```

```py
df.T
```

```py
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
i   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
L   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t
L2  a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t
```

For now, `L2` is simply a copy of column `L`. I keep `L` as the original, and I want to shuffle `L2`, so I can visually compare both. The `i` column is simply a dummy column. It's there to show that I want to keep all my columns intact, except for a fraction of `L2` that I want to shuffle.

```py
n_rows=len(df)
n_shuffle=int(n_rows*0.4)
n_rows, n_shuffle

(20, 8)
```

```py
pick_rows=np.random.permutation(list(range(n_rows)))[0:n_shuffle]
pick_rows

array([ 3,  0, 11, 16, 14,  4,  8, 12])
```

```py
shuffled_values=np.random.permutation(df['L2'][pick_rows])
shuffled_values

array(['l', 'e', 'd', 'q', 'o', 'i', 'm', 'a'], dtype=object)
```

```py
df['L2'][pick_rows]=shuffled_values
```

I get this warning:

```
C:\Users\adumont\.conda\envs\fastai-cpu\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

```py
df.T
```

I get the following, which is what I expected (40% of the values of L2 are now shuffled):

```py
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
i   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
L   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t
L2  e   b   c   l   i   f   g   h   m   j   k   d   a   n   o   p   q   r   s   t
```

You can see the notebook here (it's rendered better on nbviewer than here): https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/adumont/bc2bac1b6cf7ba547e7ba6a19c01adb6

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any idiomatic way of doing this since it's quite unusual operation, normally the whole row or column should be shuffled. What you are doing looks like a good approach.

The error `SettingWithCopyWarning` you get is a common warning that you could be operating on a copy of the original data and not a view (the origianl). For more information I would recommend checking the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas.

To avoid the error and make the code more compact you could do it as follows:

```
import random

fraction = 0.4
n_rows = len(df)
n_shuffle=int(n_rows*fraction)

pick_rows = random.sample(range(1, n_rows), n_shuffle)

df.loc[pick_rows, 'L2'] = np.random.permutation(df.loc[pick_rows, 'L2'])
```

Note that the use of `loc` here will make sure that no copy is created and everything is done on the origianl dataframe (i.e. this will not give the `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning).